# Insert a new contact - why ContentValues is not working

Tags: android, contacts, android-contentprovider, contactscontract

Following is working for inserting a new contact:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
      .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
      .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
      .build());

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
      .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
      .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
      .withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, given_name)
      .build());

getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

I'd like to switch to `ContentValues` as it is more flexible.

However, it fails when I change to `ContentValues` as follows:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
      .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
      .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
      .build());

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, given_name)
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
      .withValues(values).build()); 

getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

This only adds an empty contact.

Looks like I should call something like `withValueBackReference()` in my new version, but don't know how to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out we should get the raw contact id for insert:

```
    ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/raw_contacts");

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
    long id = ContentUris.parseId(resolver.insert(uri, values));
    uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/data");

    values.put("raw_contact_id", id);
    values.put(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, given_name)
    resolver.insert(uri, values);
```